# Why can't I double quote built-in type names in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Why can't I double quote the primary built-in type names in Postgres despite being able to double quote their aliases?  For example, these work fine

```sql
SELECT CAST (1 as bool);
SELECT CAST (1 as "bool");
SELECT CAST (1 as boolean);
SELECT CAST (1 as int8);
SELECT CAST (1 as "int8");
SELECT CAST (1 as bigint);
```

but these fail

```sql
SELECT CAST (1 as "boolean");
SELECT CAST (1 as "bigint");
```

(See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a6ad3/13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only quote *identifiers*, but not *keywords*. Data types prescribed by the SQL standard, such as `int`, `integer`, `boolean`, `bigint` etc. [are keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and, when put in quotes, are not recognised as such, producing errors. `bool` and `int8`, on the contrary, are, as you say, Postgres-specific aliases and are therefore identifiers, which allows them to be quoted.

Note that aliases follow the rules for quoted identifiers:

```
SELECT CAST (1 as BOOL); -- succeeds
SELECT CAST (1 as "BOOL"); -- fails
```

---

A little explanation of [how the parser works](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

> A token can be a key word, an identifier, a quoted identifier, a literal (or constant)

The order of precedence in the quote above is significant. When seeing an unquoted sequence of characters, the parser converts it to lowercase and first tries to match it against the known keywords. If unsuccessful, it will then try to find an identifier with that name. When seeing a quoted character sequence the parser knows that this must be an identifiers (since keywords are never quoted).

So,

1. `BOOLEAN` --> to lowercase --> `boolean` --> is keyword? yes --> done.
2. `BOOL` --> to lowercase --> `bool` --> is keyword? no --> is identifier? yes --> alias for `boolean` --> done.
3. `"BOOL"` --> quoted identifier, don't change case --> does not exist --> done.